# syslog: Service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway

Tags: linux, permissions, services, syslog

Out of the box the ESET NOD32 antivirus for Linux 64bit running on Linux Mint 18 wrongly installs the service configuration file as an executable, flooding the system log:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

with such text:

```
Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/esets.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am showing ESET NOD32 service as an example, but this applies generally to all `/lib/systemd/system/*.service` files.

Long-listing the service file:

```
ls -l /lib/systemd/system/esets.service
```

reveals the execution bits set:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 360 Sep 22 08:53 /lib/systemd/system/esets.service
```

Solution is to set the proper user rights:

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/esets.service
```

And you will no longer see such message in your `syslog`.

I have already reported this cosmetic problem to the ESET development team.

Comment: +1 in the answer. Question, why are you using an AV in Linux? (There are reasons to use an AV in certain situations, do not get me wrong)

Comment: Why is having an executable permission an issue? I couldnt find links that describe it.

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan I did some sleuthing to find this too. The warning was added in 2014. From the commit, it looks like it's just a "weird" (unnecessary) permission: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/fdb9161cd3e1a64eb9a653a6bf69596670d6e942